# Facebook messenger API. Can you disable inbox?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot, instagram-graph-api

If you use Facebook Messenger API to send and receive messages via webhook (bot) then these messages also show up, and stay in the pages inbox.

Can you disable that (inbox) so that conversations is **not** also saved there.

(I understand of course that facebook will still have the conversations, to be able to show them on the userside)

Best regards,